# How to calculate rank; local to site and globally?

Tags: discussion

With the available data points, how would you rank users, both on a site basis as well as globally?

Right now I am simply sorting on `reputation` desc, `creation_date`, `user_id`, `display_name`.

This closely approximates the order of appearance on the Users page but seems to me simplistic.

Does anyone have any thoughts about how to arrive at a valid ranking?

Assume that you have a current database of all users.

---

<sub>yes, this is me asking a question, not setting up a dev-tip ;-)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Well, would it work to rank globally based on relative rankings for each site? I'm just thinking out loud.

Here's how it works:

- For each site, the user's relative ranking is determined as a percentage.
- The percentages are averaged.

The last step isn't very good - I don't think it'll work very well, but it's an idea.

Comment: can you think aloud in detail? ;-)

Comment: @Sky: I added some more detail.